# How to define list<any> in Thrift?

Tags: list, thrift

I want to write a Thrift function which outputs a list. But, there is no such datatype in Thrift. Also, the list datatype in Thrift takes only a single datatype. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Scala has list<any> collection and the output that am getting from my server.scala is of the type list<any>

Answer (score 0):

Make container (struct) whose members are optional and have possible data types in thrift. Then, make list of that struct. It is not beautiful solution, but it works.